# Does the bijection between KG modules and K representation require the degree of the K representation to be |G|?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have read somewhere that there is a bijection between KG modules and K representations. However, I think this is only true if the K representation has the same degree as |G| correct?
From the notes on representation theory:
[image]

So a representation gives us a KG module, but the representation can be of any degree we want. However, the representation afforded by a KG module is always degree |G|. So when we say there is a bijection between KG modules and K representations, we are only talking about representations of degree |G| right?

Comment: "However, the representation afforded by a $KG$-module is always degree $|G|$". A representation is a map $G\to GL_n(K)$, and $n$ is the dimension of the $KG$-module as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: ''Degree of K representation'' means degree of K-vector space given by the KG-module.

Comment: I guess the question is: what you do you the degree of a representation is?

Comment: @CaptainLama yes correct and what would a concrete example look like? If we just take simple examples of KG modules where K=C and G is C3, the cyclic group which three elements, this KG module is supposed to induce a representation. So what exactly does the matrix for each of the elements of C3 look like?

Comment: In that case $GL(C)\cong C$ so the homomorphism $C_3\to C$ would map the elements of $C_3$ to the numbers they act by.